# How to get all capabilities of an existing user role

Tags: capabilities, user-access, user-roles

How can I get ALL the capabilities of an existing user role (eg. Author) ? I'll be using it to quickly duplicate an existing user role, then create a new role then assign or remove capabilities to a new custom role.

Comment: Something like `get_role( $role )->capabilities` e.g `get_role( 'author' )->capabilities` ? ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*I suggest not to mess with the existing roles and capabilities in its default, it might help you some trouble when you will have a bunch of custom roles and capabilities in the future.*

To answer your question, I will have an example: I need new role/user group that has almost an Administrator but don't have the the capability to edit plugins and the theme, to do that:

1. Let's say you would like to copy the existing capabilities of **Administrator**, do it by:

   ```
   $admin_role_set = get_role( 'administrator' )->capabilities;
   ```
2. You can create a new user role by using **add_role**, see the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) for more details. We can then use the list of capabilities that we have from #1 by using:

   ```
   $role = 'content_admin';
   $display_name = 'Content Admin';
   add_role( $role, $display_name, $admin_role_set );
   ```
3. By checking the [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) list from the handbook, we will be needing to remove `edit_plugins` & `edit_themes` capabilities, we can achieve that by using `remove_cap()`:

   ```
   remove_cap( 'content_admin', 'edit_plugins' );
   remove_cap( 'content_admin', 'edit_themes' );
   ```

Comment: In the 3rd step that you outline, shouldn't the role supplied to the `remove_cap` method be 'content_admin' instead of 'editor' if you're continuing the example of removing the the capability to edit plugins and the theme for the newly created custom role?

Comment: Edited as per @Kory comment